# I get syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: c#

```
string cmdStr = "INSERT INTO Names(ID,FirstName) VALUES(@ID,@FirstName)";
```

tried [] doesnt help can any one help me please?

access 2007

Comment: What do you mean by "tried []"? What *exactly* have you tried, and what happened?

Comment: [Names] tried still syntex

Comment: its not auto number its primary but not auto

Comment: Please [Copy the exception details to the clipboard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/) and [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36813659/edit) to include them.

Comment: the problem that is : string cmdStr = "INSERT INTO Students(ID,FirstName,City) VALUES(@ID,@FirstName,@City)"      is working fine

Comment: Debugger:Exception Intercepted: ExecuteSimpleQuery, DbAccess.cs line 41
An exception was intercepted and the call stack unwound to the point before the call from user code where the exception occurred.  "Unwind the call stack on unhandled exceptions" is selected in the debugger options.
Time: 23.04.2016 19:56:53
Thread:<No Name>[2064]

Comment: What about parameter handler? Try this command string: `string cmdStr = "INSERT INTO Names(ID,FirstName) VALUES(1001,'Siya')"`. Is it working?

Comment: `City` column is `not nullable`. so you're not allowed to let it be null.

Comment: works   fine     with that

Comment: string cmdStr = "INSERT INTO Names(ID,FirstName) VALUES(1001,'Siya')"   working

Answer (score 1):

> the problem that is : string cmdStr = "INSERT INTO Students(ID,FirstName,City) VALUES(@ID,@FirstName,@City)" is working fine

That is the problem, your table has 3 columns, but likely does not have a default value for `City`, if you don't tell it what to put in to `City` it does not know and will fail.

You must either always specify a city or edit the table definition to include a default value of `City`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use the proper pattern to handle your parameters, the query should work fine.

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
conn.Open();
var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstName);
```

One problem might be if the ID column is marked as an identity column. In that case you must temporarily enable identity insertion:

```
var cmdStr = @"SET IDENTITY_INSERT Names ON; " +
             @"INSERT INTO Names(ID,FirstName) VALUES(@ID,@FirstName); " +
             @"SET IDENTITY_INSERT Names OFF;"
```

Or, as stated above, if you have a column that not nullable, then of course you must include a value for it.

In any case the SqlException or OleDbException thrown should tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: var cmdStr = @"SET IDENTITY_INSERT Names ON; " +
             @"INSERT INTO Names(ID,FirstName) VALUES(@ID,@FirstName); " +
             @"SET IDENTITY_INSERT Names OFF;"       its ole db  setidentife not working  for me

Comment: and it can be null .

Comment: Please use complete sentences. It is hard to understand what you intend to say. Does the above mean you are using OleDB and all your columns in that table are nullable? OleDb cannot see if a table contains an identity column, and if you try to SET IDENTITY_INSERT on a table with no identity column, SQL Server throws an error. Examine the exception to determine which it is.

Comment: I just noticed you updated your question with Access 2007... If you are using an Access back end, forget IDENTITY_INSERT.

Comment: yea sry forget to say its access 2007 at begin

Comment: my english is not good enough to explain or undestand

Comment: i just dont get why this : string cmdStr = "INSERT INTO Students(ID,FirstName,City) VALUES(@ID,@FirstName,@City)";   works fine

Comment: var cmdStr = "INSERT INTO Names(ID,FirstName) VALUES(@ID,@FirstName)";   and this trow syntex exception

Comment: the code after is the same jsut another table to insert

Answer (score 0):

> string cmdStr = "INSERT INTO Names(ID,FirstName) VALUES(1001,'Siya')" working

- Make sure you are actually passing in a value to both variables (placing breakpoints in your code, doing a step by step debug, show yourself the values you are about to insert, etc)
- Make sure you include **' '** wrapping your char chains. Example: **'** Siya **'**

It might help you to analyze what are you doing in your code before you run your other insert statement where you insert into Students.

Comment: ok thnx    helped me to understand maybe the problem